# How many types of cells are there vs How many types of cell there are

Tags: sentence-structure, interrogatives

If I want to ask about the number of the cells' type, what is the correct way for that?

> a) How many types of cells **are** there?
>
> b) How many types of cells there **are**?

Comment: Use (a). If you really want to avoid this altogether, though, you could ask: _How many types of cells exist?_

Comment: b) is an exclamation, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question

> How many types of cell **are there**? *(this is the correct question)*

is

> How many type of cells **there are** depends on which cells you are asking about.